# How do I get a list of all cubes in arquillian?

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to add a AfterClass behaviour to dump the contents of the docker log into the junit output file. I want to do this for all cubes running for the test.

However, I can't see a way to get a list of all cubes running for the test. I see there is a CubeRegistry interface, but @ArquillianResource doesn't populate it.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for using Cube, I recommend you take a look at http://arquillian.org/arquillian-cube/#_before_stop_events maybe this would fix what you need.

Comment: I've already tried that, but by the time that runs, stdout isn't going to the junit output. Is there a way of getting list of all cubes running for the test?

Comment: I don't want to expose the CubeRegistry to test since it is something internal and prefer to avoid anyone manipulating it. I suggest you do:
```
@ArquillianResource
DockerClient dockerClient;
```
and then just use dockerclient to get the list of images that are running.

Comment: Using docker client directly will give me all running containers, not just those relevant to the test. I'm working around it by using the arq.* system properties, but it's very hacky.

Comment: Yeah, then how about create a new feature in Cube that do exactly what you need? We are always happy to receive PRs and discuss.